# Cursor index out of bound exception on listview cllick event

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, indexoutofboundsexception, android-cursor

I am performing a sqlite database operation on click event of listview as shown below:

```
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                String out = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("mynotedb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                String sql = "select description from notecont where title='"+out+"'";
                Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
                int n = c1.getColumnIndex("description");
                data = c1.getString(n);
                if(data.equals(""))
                {
                    data="";
                }
                c1.close();
                send(out, data);
            }
        });
```

But on running it gives me cursor index out of bound exception. I am also mentioning the details of logcat :

```
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at com.example.notepad.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:65)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-15 22:24:05.791: E/AndroidRuntime(6932):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest a fix.

Comment: Your cursor is returning no data. Check if there is data in database for your query, And clear data, force stop and run again.

Comment: You need to call `c1.moveToFirst()` after `Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(sql, null);`

Comment: Try to check cursor size before accessing cursor value.

Comment: when i am putting a where condition in sql and if the column title is a primary key it will return me a single entry. So why shld i check cursor value or move to the first position?

Comment: default cursor goes to next position, if you write cursor.moveToFirst(),then you can get cursor data from starting value. As per above code if in your cursor if you have 10 values you can get only 9 but not first one. thats why you can use cusor.moveToFirst()

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the `moveTo...()` methods such as `moveToFirst()` on the `Cursor` before trying to access its column data. After the query, the cursor will be pointing to row index -1 which is not a valid row.

Also check the return value of the move to make sure the cursor is pointing to a valid row after the move.

For example,

```
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
    int n = c1.getColumnIndex("description");
    data = c1.getString(n);
}
```